# $http post from angularjs to C# MVC view model, have correct List count but the values are null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following post request using $http

```
var registration = {
   userId: 23,
   groupings: [ 
           { Id: 1, Name: 'Test Group 1', Description: 'Yo' }, 
           { Id: 4, Name: 'Test Group 4', Description: 'Er' } 
]
}
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: $.param({
                code: eventCode,
                UserId: registration.userId
                Groupings: registration.groupings
            })
        })
```

And then on my action

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult New(string code, RegistrationVM model)
            {
    :
    :
    :
    }


    public class RegistrationVM  
        {
             public int UserId {get;set;}
             public IEnumerable<GroupingVM> Groupings { get; set; }
    }

public class GroupingVM{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}

   public int AnotherPropertyId {get;set;}
   public ANewClass ANewClass {get;set;}
}
```

Whenever the post happens, I would have the model properties reflect what I posted except the IEnumerable (Groupings) property. Let's say I post with 2 objects on the Groupings property, when I go to the Action, the Groupings property will have a count of 2 but every instance would have either NULL or 0 values on each object. I'm trying to figure out how I'm messing the post.

Comment: Shouldn't the params be: $.param({ code: eventCode,  model: registration  })

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it didn't work.With that, everything is empty now except code.

Comment: Try and add the string code to the RegistrationVM  class and use one parameter in the controller method. Also add the code to the registration object in the client and pass $.param({ model: registration })

Comment: Tried it, moved the properties to the VM, had the same effect, the groupings would have the right count but it's still empty properties. Should I be filling up all properties with values?

Comment: That could be the problem, the mapping mayby don't find the right object, Try and add all values of the GroupingVm class to the client array

Comment: Next step would else be to send the data with content-type json instead and stringify the object in the client before sending it

Comment: Let me try the content-type json first, seems to be easier, since I have a ton more properties I need to fill up and objects as well. How do I go about stringifying the object?

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(registration).. Another option is to use a DTO just for this method that only includes the properties you need

Comment: that worked! do you wanna add an answer so i can approve it? basically did the JSON stringify and now the List of objects and it's properties are getting recognized!!! thank you!

Comment: Great! I'll add an answer :-) just left my computer so I'll add it later, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the controller take one object as a parameter. Add the "string code" to the RegistrationVM and remove the string code as a parameter.

Then do the same when you create the client object.

Secondly, instead of using the content type "x-www-form-urlencoded" use the "application/json" which is better suited to pass objects.

Before posting the data you need to stringify the obj with `data: JSON.stringify(registration)`

For more details, read the comments on the question.